# Simple php/sql search engine

Tags: php, sql, search, search-engine

I am trying to make a simple php, sql search engine that will select everything from my database that is "LIKE" the keyword (query) and display it. However it will not work. It only displays the text "problem"(see line 32) and after hours of troubleshooting I still can not figure this out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search Engine Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="php">
// Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect("*****","*****","*****");   
if (!connection) {
    die ("Please reload page. Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// Select a databse to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("*****",$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Please reload page. Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// Search Engine
// Only execute when button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
// Filter
//$keyword = trim ($keyword);
echo $keyword;
// Select statement
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'");
// Display
$result = @mysql_query($search);
if (!$result){
echo "problem";
exit();
}


while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $search )) 
 { 
 echo $result['cause_name']; 
 echo " ";
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 }
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($search); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Nothing was found that matched your query.<br><br>"; 
 }
}
</script>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keyword">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and change:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { //$_POST['search'] just tells that there are a submit-button when submitting (and the name of it)
// Filter
//$keyword = trim ($keyword);
echo $keyword; //You're echoing out value of $keyword which hasn't been set/assigned
// Select statement

//You're always searching for the word keyword with leading and/or trailing characters
//You're not searching for a dynamically assigned value which I think is what you want
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'");

//You're executing an already defined query (assigned in $search)
$result = @mysql_query($search); //You're suppressing errors, it's bad practice.
if (!$result){
echo "problem";
exit();
}
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
// Filter
$keyword = trim ($_POST['keyword']);

// Select statement
$search = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
// Display
$result = mysql_query($search) or die('query did not work');
```

**IMPORTANT!**
`<script language="php">` isn't valid. You should type `<?php` at the beginning of php-code and `?>` to end php-code.

**UPDATE:**
You will also have to change this code:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $search )) 
    { 
    echo $result['cause_name']; 
    echo " ";
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<br>"; 
 }
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($search); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
     echo "Nothing was found that matched your query.<br><br>"; 
 }
}
```

**TO:**

```
while($result_arr = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo $result_arr['cause_name']; 
echo " ";
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
}
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
   echo "Nothing was found that matched your query.<br><br>"; 
}
}
```

***When making new code, you really should NOT use mysql_*** functions*, because they're deprecated. Look into PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: When I changed what you suggested, it still did not work and simply outputted the message that "Nothing was found that matched your query":(. Also, PHP error message saying that the "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" occurred on both lines 33 and 40. These lines are what comes after your suggested change. Line 33 is "while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $search ))" and 40 is "$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($search);" Probably just going to try to rewrite the search code.

Comment: Note: When I log into phpMyAdmin and run my SQL query on my database to select everything where the cause name is like the keyword (I just type in the keyword) it works. So I know that the problem is not with the database not working or an absence in data in my table.

Comment: @user26243491 - That was because $search is just a string containing the sql-statement and wasn't the actual result of the query. I've updated my answer, so you see what you'll have to do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding your code, we can see that:

```
$result = @mysql_query($search);
```

turns into:

```
$result = @mysql_query(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'"));
```

Which doesn't make much sense.

Change the first line to:

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'"
```

or, instead of assigning `$search` a value at all, just skip to assigning `$result` the value that `$search` currently has.

EDIT: to help you explain:

Change this:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'");
// Display
$result = @mysql_query($search);
if (!$result){
    echo "problem";
    exit();
}
```

to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'");
// Display
if (!$result){
    echo "problem";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly get what you are saying (I am very new to this) because this still won't work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: People normally create the SQL (that's the `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%keyword%'`) and assign it to a variable like `$search`. THEN, they create another variable, like `$result`, an assign it the value `mysql_query($result)`. In your case, you're putting a `mysql_query()` function with another `mysql_query()` function, which is incorrect.

Comment: Right, but after taking out the $search variable entirely, and relabeling the form it still does not work :( Thanks